# JMeter CSV data set config

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I want to sign up. There are following fields in the signup form.

1. email
2. password
3. confirm password

After signing up I am redirected to home page.

I am using CSV data set the config to create multiple users. When I look into the request I send (in view result tree) then all the data in csv are sent in the request. But the HTTP request which redirected me to home page fails.

What can be done so that I will redirect to the home page? Is there anything I am missing?

**Note:** I am redirected to the home page if I use individual data instead of CSV for the same test script.

Comment: have you added any assertions? and If it is not re-directing to home page check for which page it is redirecting. 
I hope your issue is due to may be due to user already exists with the requested data so it is not redirecting to home page.

Comment: it is redirected back to sign up page. I am using new fresh data for creating users. I am using response assertion which assert text "Logout".

If I don't use csv instead pass single value then the script works fine

Comment: Please check once your csv data.May be it is having any extra ',' or '.'

Comment: Have you verified that your CSV data is being correctly consumed by script or not? And then, try login with the same data which is shown in the Tree view. Don't pick data from CSV file, pick data from the Tree View of the Request. One more reason for this issue can be encoding of the Password in HTTP Request Sampler.

Answer (score 1):

In majority of cases it indicates missing or incorrect parameter, try the following steps:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your test plan. It might be the case that application expects a cookie and you need to send an appropriate one along with the redirect to home page
2. There might be a mandatory dynamic parameter which needs to be extracted from sign-up page response and passed to home page request. If it is the case - you'll need to get it with i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), convert to [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and use onwards.
3. The best way to get to the bottom of any unexpected behaviour is capturing traffic from real browser and JMeter using sniffer tool like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/), compare requests and ensure that requests you send with JMeter are absolutely the same as for browser (apart from dynamic parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cache / cookie situation to me. As mentioned in the above comment, add a cookie manager and see whether that helps.
Also dont forget to clear the cache and cookies before running the tests.